# Lie groups as spaces with trivial tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I have read in Frankel's [differential geometry](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1107602602) book the statement that spaces with trivial tangent bundles are Lie groups, which was given without proof.

How can I see that this is true intuitively and rigorously?

Does this assertion work in both directions?

Answer (score 6):

A Lie group $G$ necessarily has a trivial tangent bundle because left multiplication $L_g$ by an element $g\in G$ induces a map identifying the tangent space at the identity with the tangent space at $g$, and these identifications are continuous in $g$.  The converse is not true.

Comment: Worth mentioning some counterexample to the converse.

Comment: All $3$-manifolds have trivial tangent bundles.  Very few of them are Lie groups :-) @lisyarus